# How do I prove that sine is dependent only on the angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I did the following:

- Taking one triangle and writing the pythagorean formula to it: $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and hence:

$$\frac{o}{h}=\frac{\pm \sqrt{c^2-a^2}}{\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

- I took another triangle and tried to assumed that the angle would be preserved. So I added $p$ to the opposite side: $a^2+(b+p)^2=c^2$ and hence:

$$\frac{O}{H}=\frac{\pm \sqrt{C^2-A^2}}{\pm \sqrt{A^2+(b+p)^2}}$$

- I tried to write the equation:

$$\frac{\pm \sqrt{c^2-a^2}}{\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{\pm \sqrt{C^2-A^2}}{\pm \sqrt{A^2+(b+p)^2}}$$

And simplify in various ways but there was no clue of what to do next. I'm a bit confused because I'm assuming that the angle is going to be preserved, but I'm not quite sure if that is actually going to happen.

1. Is it possible to prove it this way? Perhaps the set of solutions could indicate something, but I'm not sure how I can obtain the set of solutions nor how I could use it to prove the desired proposition.

Comment: if you want the angles to be preserved all the sides must change proportionally. Adding $p$ to one side will change the triangle.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are doing and what you are looking for. Which kind of triangles are you considering ? Apparently you are considering right triangles, since $a^2+b^2=c^2$ only applies to right triangles. But then, which angle are you talking about? In any case if you increment by an additive constant ($p$) just one side of a triangle, you usually change _all_ the angles of that triangle!

Comment: The question is also very ill-formulated. The sine is defined to be a function of a single argument, that's it !

Comment: @GiovanniResta Is there a remedy to this? For example, adding it to the hypotenuse?

Comment: @YvesDaoust [Uh?](http://i.imgur.com/zO3utNw.png)

Comment: @Voyska, if you want the new triangle to have the same angles of the previous one, the only _general_ approach, as others have already pointed out, is to multiply every side by a constant. In that way the two triangles are similar, and thus they have the same angles.

Comment: @Voyska: unless you define the sine differently (which you *must* state in the question), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I know. But I'm talking about that definition.

Comment: @Voyska: are you kidding ? You want to prove that a function of a single argument is a function of a single argument ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm talking about [this definition](http://i.imgur.com/zO3utNw.png).

Comment: @Voyska: this is not a definition of the sine. What you are asking to prove is that the ratio of the height to the hypotenuses only depends on the angle (and by the way equals the sine of the angle).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. Sine has two meanings, it is the single function argument and It is also the ratio of two sides of the right triangle (opposite/hypotenuse). As this ratio depends only on the angle, one can simplify things and get $h=1$ and hence: $opposite/1=opposite$. (I guess this is correct).

Comment: @Voyska: no, the ratio of the height to the hypothenuses isn't called the sine. It equals the sine of the angle, but it has no specific name.

Answer (score 1):

All rectangle triangles with a fixed angle are similar, as they have all three angles equal. The ratios of sides of similar triangles are equal. Then the ratio of the height of the triangle to its hypothenuses is the same for the given triangle and a similar one inscribed in the unit circle. This ratio is precisely what defines the sine of the angle.